# WSS assign login token on socket?

Tags: node.js, websocket

Is it secure to assign the login token on the socket object? This would be done to avoid having to consistently send their tokens over an encrypted established WebSocket connection. The token would be sent after the connection is established as a message (frame), not a cookie or a header.